# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Can lookup label based property from legacy index

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

i create a neo4jdb,when i lookup data,it meet proplems,i use spring-data-neo4j:3.2.2.RELEASE'. it seems problem is this"User loginUser = template.lookup(User.class,"login",userName).to(User.class).singleOrNull();"
but how to revise it,helpme  thanks a lot!!
error info:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Can lookup label based property from legacy index

at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.getIndex(Neo4jTemplate.java:641)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.lookup(Neo4jTemplate.java:616)
at com.oberon.fm.neo4j.service.DatabasePopulator.loginCheck(DatabasePopulator.java:67)
at com.oberon.fm.neo4j.service.DatabasePopulator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c9138765.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:649)
at com.oberon.fm.neo4j.service.DatabasePopulator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9a39b11a.loginCheck(<generated>)
at com.oberon.fm.controller.AuthController.loginCheck(AuthController.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

my code:

```
public boolean loginCheck(String userName,String password) {
    boolean rtn = false;
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb = template.getGraphDatabaseService();
    System.out.println("0");
    Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
    System.out.println("1");
    try {
        System.out.println("2");
        User loginUser = template.lookup(User.class,"login",userName).to(User.class).singleOrNull();
        System.out.println("3");
        String userPassword = loginUser.getPassword();
        System.out.println(userPassword);

        if (new Md5PasswordEncoder().encodePassword(password, User.SALT).equals(userPassword)) {
            rtn = true; 

        }
        tx.success();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        tx.close();
    }
 return rtn;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

We're in the process of upgrading to the latest SDN version.  Having the same problem when we call repository.findByPropertyValue so I'll just be replacing it with a Cypher query.

Answer (score 0):

findByPropertyValue is deprecated now, just add methods like

```
User findUserByUsername(String username) to the repository and use it
```

Comment: I do not know well about how to use repository,could you please give me a example?Thank you very much!

Comment: UserEntity findUserEntityByEmail(String email);